# Select multiple GPUs

Tags: rendering, customization, gpu

Hope someone can help me. I have 2 Nvidia cards on board 1xK2 and 1xM40. K2 has 2 GPUs. But in the User Preference section, I can only select to use 1 K2 GPU. How do I select to use both K2's GPUs? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can select both press "Shift"+click on both GRID K2.

Comment: @Shubol3D, I tried press "Shift" key+press click on left mouse, doesn't work. I can't select to use both Grid K2. It only allows to select 1 Grid K2.